# How to change the section name of an INI file via TMemIniFile or TIniFile?

Tags: delphi, ini

Is there a method to change the section name of an INI file in Delphi, via TMemIniFile or TIniFile?

I try to find but cannot find one.

Comment: No. Either "rename" it by treating it as a text file, or "create" the new section when treating it as INI file (while the previous section remains, since there is no "delete" either - but you could overwrite=set it with an empty section).

Comment: What should happen if a section with the target name already exists?

Comment: @AmigoJack There is a "delete": it's called `EraseSection`.

Comment: @NineBerry You can check if the target name already exists with `SectionExists`.

Comment: @PhilipJ.Rayment This is the solution. You should put in in an answer here.

Comment: @Leonard It is only part of the solution, but I've now provided a way to do it.

Comment: BTW Are there comments in the sections that you want to keep? That would be a complication.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'rename section' method, but this function will do the trick for you.

```
function RenameSection(IniFile:TCustomIniFile; FromName,ToName:string):boolean; //Success returns True.
var List:   TStrings;
    n,v:    string;
    i:      integer;
begin
  if IniFile.SectionExists(ToName) then Exit(False);
  if not IniFile.SectionExists(FromName) then Exit(False);

  List:=TStringList.Create;
  try
    IniFile.ReadSectionValues(FromName,List);  //Actually reads names AND values.
    for i:=0 to List.count-1 do begin
      n:=List.Names[i];
      v:=List.ValueFromIndex[i];
      IniFile.WriteString(ToName,n,v);
    end;
  finally
    List.free;
  end;
  IniFile.EraseSection(FromName);
  IniFile.UpdateFile;
  Result:=True;
end;
```

Comment: You *must* protect your resources with `try..finally` blocks.

Comment: Also, `TStringList` has properties for accessing names and values by index, so you don't need to parse the lines to separate the names and values manually

Comment: @RemyLebeau I thought there should be methods for that, but couldn't find them.  I forgot to look for properties! :-(

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand No, `try..finally` blocks may be a good idea, even a very good idea, but they are not _required_, specially when simply illustrating the principle.  I mostly program for myself, and don't typically use them, preferring to check for potential problems (e.g. the first two lines).  Where do you suggest they should be included here?

Comment: @PhilipJ.Rayment: I strongly disagree. If `ReadSectionValues`, the `Names` getter, the `ValueFromIndex` getter, or `WriteString` raises an exception because of some unexpected scenario (including RTL bugs), your process will leak the `List` object. That is, every time this happens, your process lose some memory that can never be used again. Hence, your application will get a limited lifetime (a day, a month, a year) until it runs out of memory. And you will waste the end user's memory. In addition, maybe the `TStringList` allocates other resources than only memory. You don't know that.

Comment: You should ALWAYS, ALWAYS write `Frog := TFrog.Create; try { use Frog } finally Frog.Free end` and NEVER, NEVER, `Frog := TFrog.Create; { use Frog } Frog.Free`. Regarding "specially when simply illustrating the principle", I'd say they are particularly required there, because people reading SO answers are often rather inexperienced and will copy and learn from what you write here. They need to see the `try..finally` blocks.

Comment: Please note that I prefer the term "resources" and not (only) "memory". You need `try..finally` blocks every time you need to make sure that a block of code always is run at some occasion. For example, `Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass; try { hard work } finally Screen.Cursor := crDefault; end`. I have seen many buggy apps that get stuck with hourglass cursors because of lack of protection. Very annoying. And there are critical sections, file locks, security tokens, DB transactions, connections etc.

Comment: Idiomatic use of `try..finally` blocks (and occasional `try..except` blocks) is a fundamental part of writing robust and high-quality software in Delphi.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand  Thanks for the recommendation.  I've added try..finally.  Please answer me a question if you don't mind: Are all such normal memory/resource leaks reclaimed by Windows when the application is closed?

Comment: @PhilipJ.Rayment: Yes, this is one of the nice things about modern operating systems: the system doesn't allow any single badly-behaved application to affect the system itself or any other application -- within some limits, there are certainly exceptions. But allocated memory is always reclaimed by the system when the process is closed, as are most of the kinds of system handles the process had opened.